# Joins to return single row

Tags: sql, select, join, case

I need to write a SQL query which will populate the DELTA column. If the status has changed then YES, else NO. I have tried INNER JOINS and it would not work.

```
[Current Week Project]      |       [Last Week Project] 
ProjectID   Status  Delta   |   ProjectID   Status
       8614 Amber           |   8614    Green
       8548 Unknown         |   8548    Unknown
       2591 Green           |   2591    Green
       7813 Red             |   7813    Green
       8413 Green           |   8413    Green
       8183 Green           |   8183    Green
       7431 Red             |   7431    Red
       7399 Green           |   7399    Green
       7776 Green           |   7776    Green
       8609 Green           |   8609    Green
       8068 Red             |   8068    Amber
       8019 Green           |   8019    Green
       7799 Green           |   7799    Green
       6727 Amber           |   6727    Unknown
       7482 Green           |   7482    Green
       8384 Red             |   8384    Green

SELECT a.[Status],b.[Status] 
FROM [Current Week Project] a 
INNER JOIN [Last Week Project] b  
ON a.[ProjectID]= b.[ProjectID]
```

Comment: Share your sql and lets try to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT a.[ProjectID], a.[Status], b.[Status], 
      (CASE WHEN a.[Status] = b.[Status] THEN 'No' ELSE 'YES' END) AS Delta
FROM [Current Week Project] a 
INNER JOIN [Last Week Project] b ON a.[ProjectID]= b.[ProjectID];
```